# Setting font in pandoc to generate pdf using MiKTeX

Tags: fonts, pdf-generation, markdown, pandoc, miktex

I am new to pandoc and using it to convert set of markdown files into pdf. I would like to change the default fonts for the pdf.

The documentation gives an example to set the fonts

```
pandoc -N --template=mytemplate.tex --variable mainfont=Georgia --variable 
sansfont=Arial --variable monofont="Bitstream Vera Sans Mono" --variable 
fontsize=12pt --variable version=1.10 README --latex-engine=xelatex --toc 
-o example14.pdf
```

however this uses `xelatex` and it is recommended to use `MiKTeX`.

I have tried the above with `MiKTeX`, but without any success.

Is there a way to set the font, I am using Windows 8 with  `MiKTeX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MiKTeX is a TeX distribution that includes the LaTeX macro package (including the pdflatex and xelatex engines). (Its support for the ConTeXt macro package is [apparently](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/MikTeX) not so good though.) If you need unicode support, `pdflatex` is not such a great choice, so you might want to use `xelatex` instead.

Use `pandoc -D latex` to look at the [template](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates), save that as `myTemplate.tex`, modify the file and use for example:

```
pandoc --template myTemplate.tex --latex-engine xelatex -o output.pdf input.md
```

Comment: If I get you, you are suggesting to first convert to .tex and then to pdf. And how would I set the fonts whilst generating the .tex?

Comment: @MiKTeX After having taken a second look at MiKTeX, I corrected my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I have shifted my focus on using Context. It seems much easier and have already created a template to be used with pandoc. Thanks

Comment: Great, I find ConTeX also a lot cleaner because all basic layout functionality is in the core instead of a hundred packages. Feel free to accept/upvote my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

`I have tried the above with MiKTeX, but without any success.`

At a closer look I found that MiKTex is indeed supported, the issue was with fontspec. Once I ran the update fontspec for updated and it started working.

Comment: Can you expand on this? What is the change to the command line options and also the template? I just want to use a sans-serif font for my PDF using miktex, and I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember, I did this 6 years back and it was a side project for me. I am not really an expert in these things.